# AJAX, PHP, MYSQL method not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery method which puts an ajax call like this -

```
function getAppointmentTime(){
    //$data = getUserData();
    $docId = parseInt($( "#docSelect option:selected" ).val());
    $date = $('#patDateVal').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'func.php',
        async: false,
        data: {action: 'getDocFreeTime', docId:$docId, date:$date},
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data != 0){
                $row = '';
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    $row += '<option value="'+data[i]['Patient_ID']+'">'+data[i]['Patient_First_Name']+' '+data[i]['Patient_Middle_Name']+' '+data[i]['Patient_Last_Name']+'</option>'
                }
                $('#patSelect').html($row);
                $('#selectedPatId').val(data[0]['Patient_ID']);
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
}
```

This function call goes to my func.php where this code is there -

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
case 'getDocFreeTime':
            getDocFreeTime($_POST['docId'], $_POST['date'], $role);
            break;
}

function getDocFreeTime($docId,$date, $roles){
    return $roles->_getAppointmentTime($docId,$date);
}
```

PS -  $role is a PHP object of member class which I am creating already.

The _getAppointmentTime(...) method is in my PHP class called member, which is defined like this -

```
function _getAppointmentTime($docId,$date){
        $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime($date));

        try {

            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('call view_availibility(:id,:appdate)');
            $stmt->bindParam(":appdate", $date, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $docId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo json_encode($rows);


        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            if(ENV == 1){
                echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
            }else{
                echo 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when I am calling the first jquery method, the method is called, but onsuccess of ajax, data variable only gets a blank string.

I have other methods, which work exactly like this, but this one is not. I tried echoing random string to debug, but no luck, still get blank string in onsuccess.

Can someone please point out what is the mistake I am doing. I have many other methods which work and are exactly like this, but not this one. Maybe I am doing a noob mistake somewhere, but cannot find it out. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `$docId  and $date` must be `var docId and var date` but i think `date(javascript predefined variable)` will not work so change name and try once.

Comment: It doesnt matter. I have other codes that work properly.

Comment: ok, wait for sometime and may be you will get answer. good luck. Mean while you can check once. change $ to var and remove $ inside `data:{..}`

Comment: Also check your browser console and see if there is any error or not? if yes post here

Comment: You can debug your code line by line, this is how you can find your exact issue.

Comment: @Aparna  you are absolutely right. Appreciated your comment.

Comment: if your first code is basic javascript (not echoed as part of an PHP file) then you should remove the $ signs because they are the PHP way of handling variables, as stated by other people above.

Comment: Nothing is basic javascript. Its all JQuery. Funny thing is, some of these things are working in my friends laptop. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @NalinAgrawal please check browser console and see any error is there or not?  http://prntscr.com/avyskc      or     http://prntscr.com/avyt8g

Comment: Guys, we resolved it. It was my friend's code; and he was editing a copy of func.php, and was referring a different func.php (in different directory). That was why everything else previously written was working, but not this change since morning. Very sorry for all this confusion.